# how do i increase database size from 11GB to above 20Gb

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-xe

Every time i get below error when ever i try to import new dump into the data base.
How do i increase  db size? Any ways to resolve this, without deleting data from database?

> ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB

Comment: You are apparently using the express edition which is limited to 11GB

Comment: To follow on from @a_horse_with_no_name comment - you need to stop using Oracle Express and use Oracle Standard/Enterprise edition (and will probably need to pay for a license).

Comment: @MT0: I guess it's more "_definitely_ need to pay" then "_probably_ need to pay"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It depends on what you do with the DB: *A separate single instance Oracle Database can be installed and used as an infrastructure repository for RMAN, Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control, Automatic Workload Repository (AWR) Warehouse, Global Data Services Catalog, and Grid Infrastructure Management Repository without additional license requirements, provided that all the targets are correctly licensed. It may not be used or deployed for other uses.* [Database Licensing Information User Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC119)

Comment: ... But since the OP is talking about "data" then I'll agree that a license is going to be required (and you can then install other instances that meet the above requirements without additional licenses).

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem and found a good answer on this page: http://petesdbablog.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/oracle-11g-xe-and-the-11-gigabyte-limit/

It states that all data files (excluding the undo and temp file, which is generated by Oracle) together are allowed a maximum size of 11 GB.

You can check the current data file sizes with SQLPLUS by executing:

`select file_name, bytes from dba_data_files;`

One possible way to resolve the problem is to manually decrease the size of a data file that is rather big. You can do this with the following command in SQLPLUS (*use one of the file names returned by the command above*):

`alter database datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/YOUR_OWN_FILENAME.dbf' RESIZE 5G;`

If this doesn't work: try a larger value for the new file size.